A PDF viewer that can reload and open pdf attached files
I'm searching for a PDF viewer with two specific capabilities: firstly, the ability to open attached PDF files, similar to Foxit PDF Reader or Adobe PDF Reader. Secondly, I need it to automatically reload when changes are made, akin to Skim. This reloading feature is particularly crucial when a PDF file is accessed from iCloud and modifications are made from another computer.
Thus far, I haven't come across an application that offers both functionalities.
I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions.

What is an „attached PDF file“?

@nohillside It is often given by a paperclip sign. It allows us to add another pdf file inside a current pdf file. When you hit that paperclip sign, the attached file wil be opened.

I'm curious about the need to embed one PDF within another? From the PDF spec, it's a bit of hack, basically streaming the data inside an annotation.

This attached feature is available in Foxit PDF reader and Adobe PDF reader from long time ago. It is very convenient for having a separate annotation while reading a technical document.

The only app I can find that meets both your requirements is Nitro PDF Pro.
https://www.gonitro.com/sem/nitro-pro
It is, however, not cheap, at £14 per month or £190 one-time.

This is great. Thank you so much.
